# /usr/bin/sudo: Operation not permitted error when trying to run sudo commands via Swift process

Tags: swift, xcode, bash

In XCUI based test automation framework, I am trying to run terminal commands via Swift code which involves few internal cli tools and sudo commands. Either sudo or internal commands are getting recognised when executed via Swift `process()`.

Below is the swift function implemented to call and run shell script commands

```
import Foundation
func runShell(_ command: String) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]
    
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()
    
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    
    return output
}
```

---

```
print(runShell("sh /Users/../script.sh"))
```

**Ran shell with file**

`runShell("sh /Users/../script.sh"))`

**Output:**

```
/Users/../script.sh: line 18: /usr/bin/sudo: Operation not permitted
/Users/../script.sh: line 19: /usr/bin/python3: command not found
```

---

**Tried running the same shell file via applescript with terminal window open**

`runShell("sudo su -l admin -c \"osascript /Users/../script.sh\"")`

**Output via Applescript:**

```
zsh:1: operation not permitted: sudo
```

The above shell script and apple script works fine when it is executed directly via terminal instead of Swift. Please suggest a solution to run the shell script via Swift with maximum access and privileges.

Comment: `do shell script` is part of Standard Additions, not Terminal.app. By the way you can replace `let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String` with *swiftier* `let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!`

Comment: Thanks @vadian, I have made few changes to runShell and applescript commands but couldnt get it resolved. I am still stuck `operation not permitted: sudo`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the target sandboxed? If yes, `Process` is not allowed.

Comment: It is xctest and do not have sandbox option

Comment: Adding entitlements file and setting Sandbox value to 'No' resolved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Create entitlements file and set Sandbox value to No

1. Menu: `File` > `New` > `File`
2. Use the `Property List` template
3. Name the file as `MYPROJECT.entitlements`
4. Open the file via Project navigator
5. Add new row as below

   - Key: `App Sandbox` Type: `Boolean` Value: `No`
6. Select Project in navigator to open project settings
7. Select the `target` and navigate to `Build Settings`
8. In the list, find `CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS`
9. Set its value to the location of the `MYPROJECT.entitlements` file.
10. Do a `Clean Build Folder`, select a suitable build platform and perform a Product `Build` or `Run`.

Comment: I don't know, what I would have done without you. Great thanks!